# Async calls to cloudformation API with boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.delete_stack

I want to write a python script that calls delete_stack(). How do I have the script not wait for the stack to be deleted before returning?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread and do the `delete_stack()` call from that child thread. The parent thread will continue executing. Alternatively, you could do this in a subprocess using Python's multiprocessing module to achieve the same thing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html .

Another solution would be to use Python's asyncio with https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore . This way, you won't have to spawn child threads or subprocesses. Everything will run a single thread.